# Create a nested list from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I am trying to create a nested list from two lists

```
x1 = [1, 2]
x2 = [Z, Y]
```

The output should be like this:

```
xtotal = [[1, Z], [2, Y]]
```

My code:

```
xtotal = [[x for x in x1], [xx for xx in x2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following line. This should work.

```
xtotal = [list(t) for t in zip(x1, x2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `x1` and `x2` have the same length then

**Code:**

```
x1 = [1, 2]
x2 = [Z, Y]
xtotal = [[x1[i], x2[i]] for i in range(len(x1))]
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, Z], [2, Y]]
```